# Running xcodebuild twice from a Cocoa app (via NSTask) silently fails

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcodebuild, nstask

I have a Cocoa app that does a number of things, but among them, uses '`xcodebuild`' to clean and re-build a iOS project in XCode. The Cocoa app was developed using XCode 4.1, and runs only on OS X 10.7 (because of the NSTask termination handlers). I hadn't touched it for a few months, and after I had upgraded to XCode 4.2 I found that only the first NSTask that ran xcodebuild actually did anything. Subsequent calls do nothing.

Some details:

- The iOS project being built sits within the resource bundle of the Cocoa app. So basically, the Cocoa app is a wrapper for an iOS project. Imagine a GUI with a big red button that says: "Build me an iOS app!"
- This code worked perfectly in XCode 4.1. Task 1 executed, then in the termination handler for task 1, task 2 was called, and ran just fine. The problem is that task 2 no longer runs at all.
- I have since upgraded to xcode 4.3, which required me to also install the standalone Xcode command line tools. The code still doesn't work properly though.
- I can run both the '`xcodebuild clean`' and '`xcodebuild`' commands in Terminal with no problems.

Below is a (paraphrased) version of the offending code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self runTaskOne];
}

// Clean the iOS Project
- (void) runTaskOne
{
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@".../myproject/DerivedData/myproject/Build/Products/Debug/myproject.app/Contents/Resources/iOSProjectFolder"];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/xcodebuild"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"clean", nil]];
[task setTerminationHandler:^(NSTask *task)
 {
     [self runTaskTwo];
 }];
[task launch];

}

// Build the same iOS project that was just cleaned
- (void) runTaskTwo;
{
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:@".../myproject/DerivedData/myproject/Build/Products/Debug/myproject.app/Contents/Resources/iOSProjectFolder"];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/xcodebuild"];
[task launch];
} 

@end
```

So just to re-iterate: Task 1 (the clean) works fine. Task 2 (the build) doesn't even seem launch. This behaviour is only observed after upgrading to XCode 4.2. I must be doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: It does. Actually, I've just noticed that the terminationHandler for Task 1 is never run.
...
Aaand after a bit of searching, I've found the answer. Writing it up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though I ran into a bug in Xcode, something similar to this:
[NSTask NSPipe - objective c command line help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444178/nstask-nspipe-objective-c-command-line-help)

Basically, Xcode will hold on to the output of the NSTask if NSTask has already been launched once.

The solution was to switch the Task's standard input thusly:

```
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
```

As soon as I put that into the runTaskOne method, everything started working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), the `NSTask` instance is automatically released at the end of the `runTaskOne` method. So the completion handler is never invoked because the object that is supposed to observe the process no longer exists.

You need to keep a reference to the task by storing it in an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nicolas. What I've found is that by adding a pipe as standard input to the task like: `[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];` solves the problem. The termination handler is run, and everything's ok.