# NSTask breaks logging in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bash, logging

I'm using NSTask to run some bash commands, and have been for quite a while. Lately however, any time I try to do this, normal logging stops in the Xcode console (e.g. from NSLog or [Cocoa Lumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack)). The console still shows any output that the bash commands may have, but no further logs appear.

The logs will be appearing as normal, and will stop as soon as I execute:

```objc
NSTask *someTask   = [NSTask new];
NSArray *inputArgs = @[@"-l", @"-c", script];

[someTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[someTask setArguments:inputArgs];

[someTask launch] // This is when the logs stop
```

This problem seems to have started with the upgrade to Xcode 5.1.1. Any ideas on how to bring back my lovely messages?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Xcode. A regression.  Please file it.  As a potential workaround try creating file handles and/or pipes for the task's stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I piped all the outputs to nul, but unfortunately it still happens. Will report it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to be the resurgence of an old bug with Xcode. I found an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444178/nstask-nspipe-objective-c-command-line-help) describing it.

In short I had to change my code to:

```objc
NSTask *someTask   = [NSTask new];
NSArray *inputArgs = @[@"-l", @"-c", script];

[someTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[someTask setArguments:inputArgs];

[someTask setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]]; // <-- Added this line.

[someTask launch]
```